# downsample mp4 in windows

Tags: video, video-conversion, high-definition

I have an hd camera that records huge mp4 files in full hd. I want to publish the videos to the web, but the files are too big. How do I downsample the mp4 files so that they are 600 pixels wide and keep the same aspect ratio and high quality audio?

I am using Windows.  I have been using FlashIntegro, but it converts the files to avi format, which cannot be viewed using the video tags in html 5.  I want an mp4 format I can publish using the video tags in html 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Handbrake, it is for both Windows and Mac and can convert the files to a smaller size and keep the video frame size (ie: 1920*1080) or you can choose a smaller frame size.

It does give you various options for Web, iPod, iPhone, PSP, etc.

I use it all the time to convert my wedding films and other video work to upload to the Web (Vimeo, Youtube)